# AC circuit with no neutral output

Tags: ac

(Please forgive my ignorance, this came up when trying and failing to construct a homemade current clamp with no background in electrical engineering.)

Suppose I have an ideal wire connected to the live terminal of my 60Hz AC power outlet, then I split it, connect one end to a light bulb, let the other loop  around somewhere for 1/120 light seconds, and then connect it to the other end of the light bulb.

As a layman, it looks to me like there's a voltage across the light bulb, and it should be on, but there's no current on my neutral wire, which is strange. Am I missing something? Is it possible to shift the phase of the AC without a 2500km ideal wire so that I can actually test this?

EDIT: Here's a diagram of the circuit (hopefully intelligible despite my misuse of symbols):

[image]

where φ denotes the phase and the dotted line represents a very long wire.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate a tesla experiment on single wire transmission lines?

Comment: Note that electricity does not flow through wires at the speed of light.

Comment: This is purely theoretical for now, I don't want to plug anything to my power outlet before I'm sure I know what I'm doing...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was [cross-posted to Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445055/214960) and answered there. Don't do that!

Answer (score 0):

Current does only flow when there is a potential difference (voltage) between two points and there is a conducting path in between. I can not determine this potential difference in your setup.

Comment: My theory (which may be totally misguided) is that the electric field propagates through the wire until it reaches the left terminal of the light bulb, and then further through the fork until it reaches, at a delay, the right terminal. because the delay is exactly half a phase, I expect the voltage across the light bulb change with the sine wave, and current to flow in a sort of sawing motion, keeping it lit. It doesn't really make sense to me either though - what do I have wrong?

Comment: But wouldn't the potential, being AC and alternating polarities, reach the right terminal of the light bulb at the opposite phase (assuming the wire is long enough, the potential propagates at most at the speed of light), creating a potential difference across the light bulb and causing it to light up?

Comment: I think this question might be better posed in physics stack exchange. It has little to do with electronics.

Comment: I posted it to physics, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445055/214960)'s the link if you're interested in what they have to say. Thank you for the attention!